# How to extract items from a youtube video using youTube API 3 and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, youtube-api

Im trying to extract the title and description of a youTube video using a php file.

So far, i was able to create the url and paste into chrome browser and i got the expected results.

Now, i want to do the same thing using a PHP file called from ajax. But, i get nothing.

Heres what i've done so far:

html

```
<span class="icon iDocument" data-do='{"do":"getYoutube", "path":"xxx"}'</span>
```

ajax.js

```
$("[data-do]").click(function(event) {
    var params = $(this).data("do");
    var action = params['do'];

    switch (action) {
        case "getYoutube":
            script = "/admin/include/action/get_youtube.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: script,
                data: params
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }).fail(function() {
                alert("Error.");
            }).always(function(data) {

            })

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

get_youtube.php

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['path']) && trim($_POST['path']) != '' ) {
    $get_path = trim($_POST['path']); // for use later

    // work OK if paste in a browser (vars are harcoded for testing purposes)
    $url ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?key=keygoeshere&id=videoidgoeshere&part=snippet";

    $video = json_decode($url, true);

    $test = $video['kind']; // for testing purposes

    echo $test;

} else {
    echo 'Video path not found';
}
?>
```

Im supposed to get an alert box with some data, but i get an empty alert box?

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url ="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?key=keygoeshere&id=videoidgoeshere&part=snippet";

$video = json_decode($url, true);
```

Should be

```
$url = @file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?key=keygoeshere&id=videoidgoeshere&part=snippet");

$video = json_decode($url, true);
```

Comment: that did it, many thanks. I just needed to enable openssl on my php.ini file